# fftw3.h license - when does GPL apply here?

Tags: arm, fftw, intel-mkl, amd-processor

The fftw3 library contains a header file [fftw3.h](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/blob/master/api/fftw3.h) which includes the following statement before its license:

> - The following statement of license applies *only* to this header file,
> - and *not* to the other files distributed with FFTW or derived therefrom:

Then a [BSD 2-Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#2-clause_license_(%22Simplified_BSD_License%22_or_%22FreeBSD_License%22)) license text follows.

The purpose of this seems to be: Allow others to implement their own fftw implementation in a way that it follows the fftw API and that it is not forced to use GPL as a license. Intel, AMD and ARM offer such implementations in their CPU-vendor-optimized math libraries.

I am considering to use the fftw header in order to generate an ffi implementation that can dynamically load libraries that implement the fftw interface. I want to use this to dynamically load the CPU-specific fftw implementations.

Questions:

1. Am I allowed to do this using the BSD license for my project?
2. Is my BSD-licensed project then even allowed to dynamically load the fftw libraries, since it doesn't link to any GPL code?

Comment: cant imagine we can give legal advice here nor would it protect you if we did.  Best to get legal advice from your attorney.  Or perhaps from an open source advocacy group.